# Possible to reduce AWS Data Transfer cost by switching from HTTP API to gRPC service?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, rest, grpc

I have a web service which handles a significant volume of traffic. This traffic can be in range of millions per minute. The service is hosted on AWS EC2 behind an ELB and uses HTTP APIs. This leads to a good chunk of AWS bill comprising of Data Transfer fees. The Data Transfer Out component is mostly higher since the 50% responses from web service are somewhat large and encoded as JSON in addition to SSL negotiations.

Now gRPC payloads are smaller in size compared to similar data represented as JSON due to binary serialization. So it is possible to save upon the data transfer costs by switching from HTTP APIs to gRPC?

I couldn't find any benchmark/article anywhere correlating AWS Data Transfer costs with HTTP APIs/gRPC services. Even 5-10% savings would be beneficial.

PS: Here the clients accessing the web service are also mine. So it is possible for to make changes on both server side and client side.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, but probably not. It depends on your actual data.

If you're using HTTP for communications, then there are two components of overall message size: HTTP headers and response body. If the headers represent a significant portion of your overall message size, then it makes more sense to get rid of them by using an alternative layer-7 protocol, such as WebSockets.

If the headers aren't significant, then it depends on what your actual message content is. That's because Protocol Buffers, which is used by gRPC, performs essentially two optimizations:

- Replacement of field names with a one- or two-byte value. This can be a big savings, as long as your JSON response doesn't frequently use the same field names (ie, repeated objects). If it does, then using GZip encoding will reduce the average cost of a field name down to somewhere around 5 bytes (my observation with large files, YMMV).
- Storage of numeric values in fewer than their normal number of bits. If your message content consists of arrays of numbers, this will be a huge win. If it's mostly text, you won't see much benefit, because the same byte sequence will have to be sent in either case.

Personally, I think switching to WebSockets would be the best first step. That assumes, of course, that these messages are coming from a relatively small number of clients. If every message is from a different client, you won't save anything.